# Using android volley showing error

Tags: android-studio

When I am using android volley for inserting data into server database it is showing error cannot resolve the symbol R.

This is my dependencies in build.gradle(Module: app) where I just used a one line code

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'}/*This line*/
```

and it is showing error after gradle running.
Cannot resolve the symbol R.

Comment: Btw that's not the official Volley library. It is `compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'`

Comment: It is not working I tried this too. In main it is showing can't resolve symbol R. please help thanks in advance.

Comment: no, if I remove this code line then it works fine but I want to use volley library because I want to insert data into a server database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include this  `compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'`.It should work.

try this

```
 compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library-aar:1.0.0'
```

Comment: thanks it worked but I am inserting data from android to Php database. But it is not inserting data into the database.

Comment: Please check your php file name of table should be same as in your database.After that run your php on browser if no warning is there than check your android java code according to the tutorial you are following.

Comment: It worked, I was using a wrong Ip address for inserting values.